# How to configure an OpenWrt 10.03 router to forward an IPv6 connection to the clients?

Tags: openwrt, ipv6

So I have a TL-WR1043ND router with OpenWrt 10.03 on it. I have clients connected to it through the LAN ports. My ISP provides me a /64 IPv6 block, and I'm using PPPoE authentication.

How can I configure this "average" set-up? (IPv6 day is coming! :) ) so that the connecting clients can use (visit sites over) IPv6 and IPv4 too? (no I don't want to use any tunneling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [IPv6 HowTo on the OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ipv6). It's a pretty good starting point. I'm not going to give a detailed guide here, but a point-form summary of the broad steps to take.

First, choose a static IPv6 address from the /64 block your ISP gave you, and assign that address to the LAN side of your OpenWrt router.

Next, install and configure [`radvd`](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/radvd) in OpenWrt, to advertise itself as the default route and DNS resolver to LAN clients (clients should be configured to use [IPv6 Stateless Autoconfiguration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration_.28SLAAC.29), unless you prefer to use static IPs, or DHCPv6).

And finally, configure firewall rules (remember that there is no NAT in IPv6, so it is essential to have a stateful firewall to prevent outside hosts from initiating unwanted connections to hosts inside your LAN).

Comment: Can you please write down the exact iptables rules that is needed to forward IPv6 to the clients from the pppoe connection?

Comment: You don't *need* any `ip6tables` rules. You just need to enable forwarding: `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`

Comment: @gaskopeter: Scroll to the bottom of the [HowTo](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ipv6) guide I linked to. You should find a minimal set of `ip6tables` rules there that implement a stateful firewall.